# How to change position of drawer in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

### Change the position of the drawer in material-ui

I am trying to apply paddingLeft styling to the drawer.

For some reason, My code is not working. Any chance anyone has any idea whats happening here?

```
  <Drawer
        containerStyle={{paddingLeft:50}}
        className="app-sidebar-content"
        variant={type}
        open={type.includes("temporary") ? navCollapsed : true}
        onClose={this.props.onToggleCollapsedNav}
        classes={{
          paper: "side-nav"
        }}
      >
        <UserInfo />
        
      </Drawer>
```

Comment: is it material-ui v1.0.0 beta or v0.20.0?

Comment: I am using  v1.0.0-beta.35

Answer (score 4):

Using the modal element of the CSS API, you can achieve what you are looking for:

```
<Drawer
  open={xxx}
  onClose={yyy}
  classes={{
     paper: classes.paper,
     modal: classes.modal
  }}
>...</Drawer>
```

then

```
const styles = {
  modal: {
    paddingLeft: 50,
  },
}
```

Ref: https://material-ui.com/api/drawer/

Answer (score -1):

Which version are you using?

With the latest version of material-ui, you can pass `classes` object and style the component hierarchy.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I think we can also use `classes` in "v1.0.0-beta.35"

Comment: FYI: "Latest version" aka @Next encompasses all v1.0.0 beta versions. Have you solved your issue? If not, you may want to send the link to a Code Sand Box of your issue (such as this: https://codesandbox.io/s/kxokvropvv), so it's easier for others to see your code